# How can I convert a JSON object to a DBObject?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a JSON object obj which I want to store into MongoDB:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("title", obj1.title);
//For rules:
Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
// for rules, first create JSONArray  
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(); 

m = new LinkedHashMap();
m.put("right_connective", "&&");
m.put("attribute", "amount");
m.put("operator", "<=");
m.put("value", obj1.amount);
m.put("rank", 1);
m.put("encapsulated", "false");
ja.add(m);

m = new LinkedHashMap();
m.put("left_connective", "&&");
m.put("right_connective", "&&");
m.put("attribute", "project");
m.put("operator", "==");
m.put("value", obj1.project);
m.put("rank", 2);
m.put("encapsulated", "false");
ja.add(m);

m = new LinkedHashMap();
m.put("left_connective", "&&");
m.put("right_connective", "&&");
m.put("attribute", "type");
m.put("operator", "==");
m.put("value", obj1.type);
m.put("rank", 3);
m.put("encapsulated", "false");
ja.add(m);

m = new LinkedHashMap();
m.put("left_connective", "&&");
m.put("attribute", "car");
m.put("operator", "==");
m.put("value", obj1.car);
m.put("rank", 4);
m.put("encapsulated", "false");
ja.add(m);

obj.put("rule", ja);



Document doc = Document.parse( obj.toString() );
BasicDBObject dbObject = mapper.readValue(obj, BasicDBObject.class);
collection.insert(dbObject);
```

I'm getting an error that "mapper cannot be resolved to a type". Which import statement do I need to include? Otherwise, can you suggest alternate methods? I don't want to go the MongoDocument route since the insertOne() function is skipping some documents while writing to DB.

Comment: Try to use `JsonObject` instead of `Map` for variable `m`

Comment: But then, how should I convert it into DBObject? Can you elaborate a bit? I'm a newbie in using Mongo with java. If you can write for a single map object and write the line to convert into DBObject, that would help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a mapper if you are working with `org.json.JSONObject`:

```
 DBObject object = (DBObject) JSON.parse(obj.toString());
 collection.insert(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using jackson.Create ObjectMapper  like below to resolve "mapper cannot be resolved to a type"

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; //import statement

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); //initialization
```

Comment: It's showing an error: "com.fasterxml" cannot be resolved.

Comment: can you specify what type of json imports you are using in your code. This link https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/ may help for you.

Answer (score 0):

'com.mongodb.util.JSON' is deprecated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).